# import and export in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

According to this question [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file). It seems a lots of people are interested in breaking big Javascript projects into small modules and export/import modules for code reuse.

After some research, import/export are designed for this feature. According to the references, they're initially defined in ES6.

**Update**

**Latest version of main browsers shipped with this feature implemented. To have the latest status, please always refer to the References.**

(If you're using nodejs, Modules (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/modules.html) is the best aproach)

**Refrerences**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: related questions: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516906/which-browsers-support-import-and-export-syntax-for-ecmascript-6?rq=1,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355486/what-ecmascript-6-features-can-i-currently-use-in-browsers?lq=1

Comment: **NOTE:** modules have as of the time of this comment shipped in chrome and safari.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for pointing out. It's a good news. Updated my answer and references are always the best place to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current versions of JS there are a few methods of doing this. Require uses the AMD design pattern, and is the standard for frontend dependency injection / module loading. Frameworks such as Angular use this method.

Here is a link to the require docs. 
http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Time goes by... Today I would rather suggest using Babel (within browserify or webpack) to turn ES modules into plain old javascript.

Then you have the full power of import/export syntax.

Require/AMD/CommonJS is just getting deprecated anytime soon.