# how to enable imports/ exports in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

chrome, Firefox support imports and exports with a flag

http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

chrome - 60

```
Support can be enabled via about:flags
```

Firefox - 54

```
Support can be enabled via about:config
```

after going to `about:flags`, `about:config`
which feature have to enable to use imports and exports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which browsers support import and export syntax for ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516906/which-browsers-support-import-and-export-syntax-for-ecmascript-6)

Comment: common, it's complete different question

Comment: It contains the answer to your question and thus is complete duplicate.

Comment: A good answer to this question should answer how exactly these browsers are supported - and [it does it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086319/3731501). This is how it's working for older questions, they get up to date answers with time.

Comment: The question is a superset of your question and contains [**the exact answer to your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086319/3731501). That's what is called a dupe on SO. I'm not sure what we're talking about.