# Cannot import from redom library

Tags: javascript, html, import, es6-modules, lib

I am trying to import [redom](https://redom.js.org) library but keep getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null`

My code is listed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='test.js'></script>
    <script src="libraries/redom.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script>
      const { el, mount } = redom;
      const hello = el('h1', 'Hello World');
      mount(document.body, hello);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change `const { el, mount } = redom;` to `import { el, mount } from 'redom'`, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

The path is correct, and redom.min.js is not broken.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `redom`, but perhaps the error is because the script is called before the DOM is loaded? Try putting it in a `window.onload` handler?

Comment: And yes, the `import` statement is [barely supported in web browsers right now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086319/2397327).

Comment: @LambdaNinja window.onload worked! Thanks. But do I need to use onload handler everytime I use redom?  The redom documentation was not even talking about onload handler.

Comment: I'm glad I helped! AFAIK the convention for most JavaScript is to wrap the whole JavaScript code in a `window.onload` (or a jQuery `$(document).ready()`) so that all runs after the page loads and there are no errors with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Adding attribute `type="module"` to the script which loads `redom` may fix problem ( if you use latest Chrome ) :

```
<script src="libraries/redom.min.js" type="module"></script>
```

However the exception is expected as the `import` statement isn't supported by majority of the browsers, see quote:

> Note: This feature is not implemented in any browsers natively at this
>   time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as the Traceur
>   Compiler, Babel, Rollup or Webpack.
>
> Source: [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try ES2015, you can also use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import { el, mount } from 'https://redom.js.org/redom.es.min.js';

      const hello = el('h1', 'Hello RE:DOM!');

      mount(document.body, hello);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(you need a modern browser, like the latest Chrome)