# how can I add javascript code from import into iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to inject javascript code below into `iframe` element but I don't understand how I can achieve this. because since the code is written in ES6, I can't find other way I can put the code into `iframe` element.

I'm aware that I can add javascript into iframe this way,

```
var scriptTag = "<script>alert(1)</script>";
$("iframe").contents().find("body").append(scriptTag);
```

but I don't understand how I can do that with code below.

```
import finder from '@medv/finder'
document.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    const selector = finder(event.target)
    console.log(selector) 
}, true)
```

any help would be so appreciated :)

Comment: @JacobGoh I mean, you have to compile the javascript code that will be injected before It injects into the iframe.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that without transpiling with Babel or something first. You need to find a way to bundle `@medv/finder` within the code you want to inject

Comment: @CodingIntrigue It's saying `exports is not defined` when I bundle it and  inject the code. how can I fix it?

Comment: maybe you should see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516906/which-browsers-support-import-and-export-syntax-for-ecmascript-6, finally you´ll find there other ways to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which browsers support import and export syntax for ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516906/which-browsers-support-import-and-export-syntax-for-ecmascript-6)